# Range input refuses to change background color and height

Tags: css, sass

So I'm working on a website for a radio station and have encountered an issue. The range input we use for volume literally refuses to change its background color and height. I'm using SASS (which makes it a scss file type) for the purposes of this project.

I've done some research and have tried a few things the Internet recommended, but unfortunately, none have worked. I have tried using `background`, `background-color` and even `color` fields to try and fix my issue. I have made sure to overwrite everything that might be stopping me from doing so by setting the `-webkit-appearance` to `none`.

This is the content of the slider and its parent elements in my hbs file:

```
<div class="rootplayer">
  <div>
    <img class="picture" alt='Artist art' src="{{songart}}" width="170px">
    <div class="playerinfo">
      <p>On air: {{dj}}</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Up next: AJS Show</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Currently playing: {{songTitle}}</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Current Listeners: {{currentListeners}}</p>
    </div>
    <audio controls="" id="player">
      <source src="http://radio.nowhits.uk:8000/radio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div class="playercontrols">
    <i class="fas fa-play" onclick="play()" id="play"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-pause" onclick="pause()" id="pause"></i>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0.5" step="0.01" class="slider" id="volume">
    <script src="scripts/volume.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/playpause.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the content of the slider object in my scss file:

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1px;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: red;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Obviously, the expected output should be a red background and a height of 1px (should be a pretty thin line), but instead, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaOLV.jpg).

Comment: Which browser do you use? I tried your code in chrome, changed the `height` to `1px` and it works perfectly.

Comment: @ItzhakAvraham Interesting, I use Chrome as well... Let's talk about what you used, did you use vanilla css or (node-)sass as mentioned in the post?

Comment: Of course, I'm using scss (your code is scss and not sass, there is a difference). It's wired you're using chrome, because the range input looks different than your attached picture. Why the range tuner is a circle in your picture?

Comment: This is the reason, I didn't include this in the question because it is for what I asked not a big difference, but here we go (check the post once again, I have added the styling for the slider thumb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this :

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: red;
}

.slider::-moz-range-track {
  background: red;
}

.slider::-ms-track {
  background: red;
}
```

Look at this site for more customizations : http://danielstern.ca/range.css

Comment: Ok that seems to have kind of fixed my issue, I would like to address that it's behaving really weird after this, let me show you, [this](https://imgur.com/a/HmDiA7x) is what it's doing now

Comment: I do not understand why you put height to 0px : it will hide the track. What kind of result do you expect ? Could you provide a drawing ?

Comment: I don't know why I set it to 0px either, it's at 1px now though but I'm trying to get rid of the gray square at the moment

Comment: Tried a lot of things to get rid of that... None have worked, here's what I tried: `background: transparent; background-color:red` (in all 3: .slider, .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, .slider::-moz-range-track), tried setting all kinds of backgrounds to transparent but nothing

Comment: Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/cnxy9hmz/
There is no gray background under the range control...

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the feedback, will research and update the original question